# Getting image height on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set div#top height equals image height. I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTopHeight();
});

/*
* window resizing
*/
$(window).resize(function() {
    setTopHeight();
});

/*
* setting #top height by banner height
*/
var setTopHeight = function() {
    var bannerHeight = $('#banner-image').height();
    $('#top').height(bannerHeight + 'px');
};
```

It works on resize, but doesn't at reload. I've tried sth like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        setTopHeight();
    }, 50);
});
```

and it works, but of course it's not solution. Can somebody tell me why console.log returns 0?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($('#banner-image').height());
});
```

Comment: Is banner-image the id of img tag or it's the image wrapper div id?

Answer (score 1):

`.ready` won't work because your image has not been loaded yet. use `.load`

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready` fires when the DOM is ready, but the image might still be downloading - so no height yet. You might use [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on the image.

```
$('#banner-image').on('load', function () {
    setTopHeight();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) acts as an event handler. `.load()` is a shortcut for `.on('load, function(){})`. It will be triggered once the image/element if fully loaded.

Example 1:

```
$('#banner-image').load(setTopHeight);
```

Example 2

```
$('#banner-image').load(function(){
    setTopHeight();
});
```

Example 3

```
$('#banner-image').on('load', setTopHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .load() instead .ready()

```
$(window).load(function() {
      setTopHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The image load is in a second HTTP round after your document. so you need listen to image load

```
$('#banner-image').load(setTopHeight);
```